# Error: - could not initialize class org.apache.maven.plugin.war.util.webappstructureserializer

Tags: java, maven

I am working on spring maven and I am facing this error in pom.xml

**could not initialize class org.apache.maven.plugin.war.util.webappstructureserializer** in line 1

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ibank</groupId>
    <artifactId>ibank</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>ibank</name>
    <description>With REST</description>

    <build>
        <finalName>ibank</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

I have tried few solutions available which said to change version but still it showed the same errors.